# Agregar valor a base de datos en mysql mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente html

```
<select name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod">
    <option value="Efectivo">Efectivo</option>
    <option value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta</option>
    <option value="Transferencia">Transferencia</option>
</select>
```

Y con las siguientes dos lineas de codigo en javascript estoy obteniendo el valor del `<select>`

```
var paymentMethod = document.getElementById("paymentMethod");
paymentMethod = paymentMethod.options[paymentMethod.selectedIndex].text;
```

Hasta ahi todo funciona correctamente pero al intentar enviar el valor de `paymentMethod` que lo hago mediante una solicitud GET:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "/usuario/pos/caja.php?code="+code+"&quantity="+quantity+"&paymentMethod="+paymentMethod, true);
```

Cuando se añade la información a la base de datos todo aparece correctamente excepto la columna de metodo de pago que en vez de aparecer alguna de las opciones: efectivo, tarjeta o transferencia, aparece [object HTMLSelectElement].

Comment: A ciegas poco vamos a adivinar que te pasa. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender a formular buenas preguntas y como funciona este sitio. Luego puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que falta para que tenga un [example], gracias.

Comment: @masterguru Que tal ahora.

Comment: Ahora miro tu código a ver si ahora puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Prueba cambiar la segunda asignación, pues estas repitiendo el nombre y por lo que sea se confunde. Y yo usaria `value` y no `text`... algo asi como: `paymentMethodValue = paymentMethod.options[paymentMethod.selectedIndex].value;`  y luego en los parametros lo usas así:  `"&paymentMethod="+paymentMethodValue, true);`

Comment: @masterguru ya probé de esa manera y aparecia el mismo resultado

Comment: Pues no deberia ocurrirte. Míralo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/tgk56cLa/  (abre la consola pulsando sobre `Console(beta)` si no esta abierta para ver los resultados de los console.log).  Es más, prueba tu código alli directamente a ver que ocurre, quizas has omitido algo en la pregunta y alli lo verás más claro.

Comment: @masterguru es correcto, como te digo ya verifiqué que el dato del `<select>` lo obtengo pero al momento de hacer el INSERT a la base de datos en la base de datos aparece como  [object HTMLSelectElement] pero tanto en console.log como en un alert que usé para comprobar me aparecia el texto esperado.

Comment: Pues agrega a la pregunta los siguientes pasos, es decir, como recibes los GET, como haces el INSERT, etc... Si hasta aquí lo tenemos ya depurado y es correcto por algun motivo algo esta mal más adelante, pero no podremos ayudarte si no sabemos como lo haces despues.

Comment: @masterguru ya lo solucioné, el error no está en el backed, el error es que primero se estaba ejecutando el xhttp.open por lo que enviaba la solicitud sin el valor. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Ok, perfecto, me alegro que lo hayas encontrado. Como puedes ver ese orden no es el que habias puesto en la pregunta, y de este modo era muy dificil adivinar eso justamente. Recomiendo que leas [ask] para la próxima vez que tengas nuevas preguntas y sobretodo lo del [example] para aprender como poner un ejemplo válido y correcto, sino pueden pasar estas cosas e ir dando palos de ciego.